# set all div's height similar according to their first div in the row using javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have three div `p, p1, p3` which is inside in div `r` having different height
I want to set all div inside the div r similar to the first div inside the `r` as per their classname using object:

```js
var firstChild = document.querySelector(".r:first-child");
var descendant = firstChild.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2,.p3");
var p, p2, p3;
[].forEach.call(descendant, function(itm) {
  itm.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  var ch = document.getElementsByClassName("p");
  for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    var ar = ['p', 'p2', 'p3']; //are the class name 
    p = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight / 1.5; // height value for p 
    p2 = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight + p; // height value for p2 
    p3 = p2 / 1.5; // height value for p3 
    var colors = {}; //using dynamic 
    colors[ar[0]] = p;
    colors[ar[1]] = p2;
    colors[ar[2]] = p3;
    ch[i].style.height = colors[ch[i].className] + "px"; //problem comes here this shows undefined
    itm.style.height = ch[i].clientHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "asfaf";
  }
});
```

```css
.p,
.p2,
.p3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.p {
  height: 50px;
}
p2 {
  height: 100px;
}
p3 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="p">fgdsgs</div>
    <div class="p2">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="p3">sdgdfg</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

as you've seen `p, p1, p2`has different value in javascript , i want to make all div in same height

example = if the first div inside r is p the make all div inside r will be according to their value described (`ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight / 1.5` ) i javascript , similarly if the first div is p3 then all div(`p, p2, p3`) inside r will be get same height described in javascript which is `p2/1.5`
 using dynamic propery object , whats the problem in my code ?

Demo = https://jsfiddle.net/m2gj5dt5/

Comment: no need for script to do this if you use css flexbox

Comment: @charlietfl See my current hat now. `:D`

Comment: im here you didnt give answer

Comment: @Anjali Did you refresh the page and see the answer?

Comment: @Anjali I really would like to attempt. Can you please tell exactly what you are attempting to do? You have three divs of growing heights. That I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is, I would get the largest height and set it to all the `p` tags.

```js
var firstChild = document.querySelector(".r > :first-child");
var descendant = document.querySelectorAll(".p, .p2, .p3");
var p, p2, p3;
for (var el = 0; el < descendant.length; el++) {
  debugger;
  var itm = descendant[el];
  itm.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  debugger;
  var ch = document.getElementsByClassName("p");
  for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    var ar = ['p', 'p2', 'p3'];
    p = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight / 1.5;
    p2 = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight + p;
    p3 = p2 / 1.5;
    var colors = {};
    colors[ar[0]] = p;
    colors[ar[1]] = p2;
    colors[ar[2]] = p3;
    debugger;
    ch[i].style.height = colors[ch[i].className] + "px";
    itm.style.height = ch[i].clientHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "asfaf";
  }
}
```

```css
.p, .p2, .p3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="p">fgdsgs</div>
    <div class="p2">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="p3">sdgdfg</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Also, you forgot the `.`s in the CSS for `p2` and `p3`.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qsj1444p/**

Comment: could you make it in jsfiddle `colors[ch[i].className]` value is undefined why

Comment: @Anjali I don't see a difference between JSFiddle and this. Let me check the problem why `undefined` is coming up.

Comment: @Anjali I tried adding a debugger. Seems like that line is not even getting executed. Am I doing something else? https://jsfiddle.net/cko56fgp/

Comment: thanks but didnt work in dreamweawer , let me check again

Comment: @Anjali **1.** Don't use Dreamweaver. **2.** Dreamweaver uses a less capable browser, which is not good for displaying all the complex JavaScripts.

Comment: actually i wanted to do that to make all div in same height which is inside `r` according to the first div of `r` ... read example in my question

Comment: @Anjali Can you please run my updated code in the answer?

Comment: could you give a jsfiddle

Comment: @Anjali Can't you click on the run snippet in my answer? Anyway, here's the same exact code in Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/dco781og/**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131424/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-anjali).

Comment: no yar var is those variables are imprtant can you look up in that way which I asked